# Python function to hash a python function

Tags: python, reflection, hashcode

I'm working on a sort of distributed build system. The system allows execution of snippets of scripts as build steps. I need to be able to hash these snippets of code in a way that comments and doc strings don't affect the hash. I'm getting part way there by using the ast module to parse the code, then doing an ast.dump and hashing the resulting string. The natural next step for me is to clear the first Expr(str()) node in the body of every FunctionDef node.

This is the best solution I've found so far.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

```
import ast
import hashlib
import inspect

def _remove_docstring(node):
    '''
    Removes all the doc strings in a FunctionDef or ClassDef as node.
    Arguments:
        node (ast.FunctionDef or ast.ClassDef): The node whose docstrings to
            remove.
    '''
    if not (isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) or
            isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef)):
        return

    if len(node.body) != 0:
        docstr = node.body[0]
        if isinstance(docstr, ast.Expr) and isinstance(docstr.value, ast.Str):
            node.body.pop(0)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def hash_function(func):
    '''
    Produces a hash for the code in the given function.
    Arguments:
        func (types.FunctionObject): The function to produce a hash for
    '''
    func_str = inspect.getsource(func)
    module = ast.parse(func_str)

    assert len(module.body) == 1 and isinstance(module.body[0], ast.FunctionDef)

    # Clear function name so it doesn't affect the hash
    func_node = module.body[0]
    func_node.name = "" 

    # Clear all the doc strings
    for node in ast.walk(module):
        _remove_docstring(node)

    # Convert the ast to a string for hashing
    ast_str = ast.dump(module, annotate_fields=False)

    # Produce the hash
    fhash = hashlib.sha256(ast_str)
    result = fhash.hexdigest()
    return result

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Function 1
def test(blah):
    'This is a test'
    class Test(object):
        '''
        My test class
        '''
    print blah
    def sub_function(foo):
        '''arg'''
print hash_function(test)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Function 2
def test2(blah):
    'This is a test'
    class Test(object):
        '''
        My test class
        '''
    print blah
    def sub_function(foo):
        '''arg meh'''
print hash_function(test2)
```

Comment: What about a function with closure?

Comment: ---I think you should use RegEx for this.--- Look into building a parse tree that is valid for all Python statements. You'll find a good many other uses for it besides this, I wager.

Comment: *In my opinion*, RegExes are only good for quick find-replace. It's better to avoid them in programs.

Comment: @dhu are you asking whether this will work for closures? I've tested it with functions within functions and classes within functions and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Hosch250 I don't think it's a good idea to build another parser when python comes with a module already that already parses python perfectly. I would see this as over complicating the solution.

Comment: Oh, well use that parse tree to find and remove comment nodes?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yeah, the `---` notation is strike-out markup in answers/chat. Apparently not in comments.

Comment: @Hosch250 Oh, I see. :P

Comment: @Luke I meant function that carries a closure with it. For example `def make_poly(a, b, c): 
    def inner(x): return axx+b*x+c 
    return inner` 
(I don't know how to indent them well in comments). When you call `f1 = make_poly(1, 1, 1)` and `f2 = make_poly(2, 2, 2)` you get two different functions with the same source code. `f1.__closure__` or `f1.func_closure` shows 3 closure attributes it has, each corresponding to the coefficient `a`, `b`, `c`. Check out `dir(f1)`

Comment: @dhu Thanks for this. I understand what you're saying. A user might want a different hash for f1 and f2. In my code both would hash to the same number. This is actually what I want, because I only want changes to be spotted when there is a change to the source code, but I understand in other cases this might not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for [`ast.get_docstring`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/ast.py) your code more or less does what it does. Here is their code for reference:

```
def get_docstring(node, clean=True):
    """
    Return the docstring for the given node or None if no docstring can
    be found.  If the node provided does not have docstrings a TypeError
    will be raised.
    """
    if not isinstance(node, (AsyncFunctionDef, FunctionDef, ClassDef, Module)):
        raise TypeError("%r can't have docstrings" % node.__class__.__name__)
    if not(node.body and isinstance(node.body[0], Expr)):
        return
    node = node.body[0].value
    if isinstance(node, Str):
        text = node.s
    elif isinstance(node, Constant) and isinstance(node.value, str):
        text = node.value
    else:
        return
    if clean:
        import inspect
        text = inspect.cleandoc(text)
return text
```

A couple of the things they mention are only a concern for Python 3+ like `AsyncFunctionDef`. Also, it seems `Constant` is a grammar rule introduced in Python 3+. (However, you may want to account for this in the future.)

You seem to be also removing docstrings from `ClassDef`, I am not one hundred percent sure, but you may also want to add `Module` as well.

There is also a [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer). However, I find it rather weird stylistically compared to your current method of looping. So... I'm not confident in making any comments about whether you should be using it or not. Nevertheless, I'm putting it out there so you are aware in case you weren't.

Comment: thanks for this. Yes I wrote it for python 2.7. Any suggestions for making it work with both? I included ClassDef because it's possible to define a class inside of a function, but I don't think its possible to declare a new module inside of a function which is why I left it out. I did try with ast.NodeTransformer and ast.NodeVisitor, but both seemed to be a few more lines of code and more difficult to read.